# Inserting a new record in the middle of the table

Tags: mysql, insert

I want to insert a new row in the middle of the table. I am using MySql. How can I do this?

I have the following records in my table:

```
ZipCode  CityName 

60101,   Addison
60004,   Arlington Heights
60502,   Aurora
62223,   Belleville 
61008,   Belvidere
60105,   Bensenville
60402,   Berwyn
60108,   Bloomingdal
61701,   Bloomington
```

and I want to insert a new record, but not in the end of the table.

For example I want to insert :

```
60103, Bartlett
```

after the third record, so the final table should look like:

```
60101,   Addison
60004,   Arlington Heights
60502,   Aurora
60103,   Bartlett
62223,   Belleville 
61008,   Belvidere
60105,   Bensenville
60402,   Berwyn
60108,   Bloomingdal
61701,   Bloomington.
```

Any suggestion will help me. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The order of the records is dependent on ORDER BY clause inside SELECT statement.

If you doesn't specify ORDER BY then RDBMS (MySQL, Oracle, ...) can choose any ordering it likes.

So just insert your record, and if you issue

```
SELECT * from MY_TABLE
ORDER BY CityName
```

you will get the desired result.

Comment: I was thinking I can insert a new row in a certain position. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to `INSERT` at that specific point.  All you need to do is `INSERT` the record and then use `ORDER BY` to sort the data:

```
INSERT INTO yourtable (ZipCode, CityName)
VALUES (60103, 'Bartlett')
```

Then

```
SELECT ZipCode, CityName
FROM yourtable
ORDER BY CityName
```

Comment: It would probably be easier to just have an index on the zip.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can't insert into table by specify a position of record. But you can use order and [other select statement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Select_%28SQL%29) to show your data. Try:

```
INSERT INTO Yourtable (ZipCode,CityName) VALUES ('60103', 'Bartlett');
```

and then:

```
SELECT ZipCode,CityName FROM yourTable ORDER BY CityName ASC;
```